# Measurement and probability

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, measurement-problem

In the $\left\{\left|j_1j_2;jm\right\rangle=\left|ls;jm\right\rangle\right\}$ basis, I've got the state ket $$\left|\alpha\right\rangle=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\left|11;20\right\rangle + \sqrt{6}\left|01;10\right\rangle - \left|11;10\right\rangle - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left|11;00\right\rangle\right).$$ Now I would like to calculate the probability that a measurement gives $j=1$, but I'm facing a conceptual difficulty: is this probability given by

1. $$\mathcal{P}\left(j=1\right)=\left|\sum_{q=0,1}\left\langle q1;10|\alpha\right\rangle\right|^2,$$
   or
2. $$\mathcal{P}\left(j=1\right)=\sum_{q=0,1}\left|\left\langle q1;10|\alpha\right\rangle\right|^2 \,?$$

Comment: It would be nice if you could rationalize on your own which one is it. One way of seeing this is by thinking of the projector operator corresponding to the eigenspace selected by the result (of a hypothetical measurement giving $j=1$). You can build it from the states that have $j=1$ and let's call it $P$. Normalize it such that $P^2=P$. Then the probability of obtaining such result will be $\mathrm{Tr} \left[P |\alpha\rangle \langle \alpha| \right] = \langle \alpha | P | \alpha \rangle$.

Comment: @secavara, so the sum of squared moduli, 2.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I'm not very sure about your notation. What do you mean by $|j_1j_2;jm\rangle$ being equal to $|ls;jm\rangle$? There's a nontrivial conversion between the two bases utilizing Clebsch-Gordan coefficients. In which of these bases should I read $|\alpha\rangle$? (Not that it would affect the answer in this particular case, but still.)

Comment: @TheVee at first I also got confused, in most cases one can just drop the $j_1,j_2$ (or $l,s$ in this case) from the total angular momentum eigenstates $|j,m\rangle$. But these are indeed in the basis of total angular momentum, in particular they have a superposition of states that have the same $s$ but different $l$. Notice that these are not from the decoupled $|l,m_l\rangle \otimes |s,m_s\rangle$ basis. It seems OP has the same assignment as VincenzoVentriglia. See the question: [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/386380/time-evolution-spin-1-particle#comment867602_386380).